# Running Node on windows

Tags: javascript, windows, server

I develop a Node server app. as I develop, I test it with 'run npm' command, which launches the server, then I test it from Chrome and\or Postman.

Now I wish to roll this app (it's a REST service) out to production server. Ours is a Windows server, so how is it usually done? I mean Node is its own server, so is it normal to copy the files over to a directory on the server and set an 'rpm run' to execute there on server start, or do people then typically use IIS as the server? Is something like IISNode a popular way to do things these days...?

Answer (score 1):

If you want my opinion, I myself always run my node projects in somewhere out of windows platform, like containerized or Linux-based production environments.
But you can use nssm.exe to make a windows service with failure recovery and auto startup features from your node project as easy as you want. I can clarify more if you want.
Just visit [this article](https://nssm.cc/download)